# How to find a property of an object in a list in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of employers and i need to retrieve an employer's id according to its name from a list. Following function is getting the employer list from another api.

```
getEmployers(): void {
    this.employersService.getEmployers().subscribe((employerData: Employer[])=>{this.employerList = employerData})
  }
```

I need to find the employerId of an employer whose name is "John" from that employerList.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Same way you'd do it in JavaScript, this is nothing to do with the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
const employer = this.employerList.find(x => x.name === "John");
return employer && employer.id;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

getEmployers(): void {
    this.employersService.getEmployers().find(employee=>employee.name==='John').subscribe((employee)=>{
/** this is employee john**/
this.employee= employee;
})
  }